# KDB: Create Empty Table Using Dynamic Columns

Tags: functional-programming, formatting, kdb

I want to create an empty table with the following static columns: 
`date`, `security`, `active`, `horizon`

and an undefined number of additional columns that are represented by the following variables: 
`outFactor`, `subFacCols`

The columns represented by outFactor and subFacCols are float types. How can I create a dummy table with the aforementioned columns?

**Example:**

These are the first 5 columns, not including `subFacCols`

```
dummyTable:flip (`date`security`active`horizon,outFactor)!(`date$();`int$();`boolean$();`int$();`float$())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the key and value of the dictionary to be of the same length, therefore the following should work:

```
q)outFactor:`price`size
q)subFacCols:`bestBid
q)dummyTable:flip (`date`security`active`horizon,outFactor,subFacCols)!(`date$();`int$();`boolean$();`int$()),(count[outFactor]#`float$()),count[subFacCols]#`float$()
q)meta dummyTable
c       | t f a
--------| -----
date    | d
security| i
active  | b
horizon | i
price   | f
size    | f
bestBid | f
```

Uses: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#take